# CodeIgniter SQL query missing columns

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have this SQL query which is something like this in normal sql syntax

```
SELECT *
FROM question
LEFT JOIN abcd_selection ON question.questionID = abcd_selection.questionID
WHERE question.SurveyID =21
```

This works perfectly fine I get what i wanted. However when I switch this over to CI, it does not work strangely. The questionID column disappears for rows that do not have a match with abcd_selection.

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('question');
$this->db->join('abcd_selection','question.QuestionID = abcd_selection.QuestionID', 'left');
$this->db->where('question.SurveyID', $input_qid);

$query = $this->db->get();
```

Can anyone solve this??

Comment: `question.questionID = abcd_selection.questionID` != `question.QuestionID = abcd_selection.QuestionID`, double check your `questionID`/`QuestionID` case

Comment: yes both tables are QuestionID.

Comment: Your issue is that since both your column names are `QuestionID`, when a row exists in `abcd_selection` you get the same value twice, but when a row does not exist the second `QuestionID` is `NULL`. You could try using an alias -> `$this->db->select('*,question.QuestionID as QID');`. That way you can select the `QID`, even when `abcd_selection.QuestionID` does not exist, and you won't end up with `NULL`

Comment: I will post it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When joining 2 tables, which have the same column name, you will get a `NULL` value when there is not a row that matches in the second table.

```
question.SurveyID  question.QuestionID  abcd_selection.QuestionID
1                  2                    2  //matching row in abcd_selection
2                  3                    NULL //no matching row in abcd_selection
```

Since the column names are the same, php will select the last instance of `QuestionID`, which will be `NULL` when a matching row does not exist.

One way to work around this is to select the column as an alias

```
$this->db->select('*,question.QuestionID as QID');
```

Now you can select `$query['QID']` even when a `abcd_selection.QuestionID` does not exist.